# Terraform azure provider gave me "features required field not set"

Tags: azure, terraform

This code gave me error, even with the feature block.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12" 
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
  
}

provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = "xxxxx"
  subscription_id = "xxxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxxx"
  client_secret   = "xxxxx"
  alias           = "prod"
  features {}
}
```

What's wrong??? For azurerm version 2.0, I know features block is needed but I tried several times the error always comes up.

Comment: Did you run terraform init after changes?

Comment: You could post your solution if this issue has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this today and when I removed `alias` field and it worked!
Related to this bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26312#issuecomment-801468683

Answer (score 0):

This problem already solved,..

Actually, i need "alias" here because i'm using terraform for multi-subscriptions deployment..

For every resource blocks, i just need a "provider" attribut to define the provider they use.. in my case:

```
provider = azurem.prod
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises from a subtle quirk in Terraform's behavior regarding provider aliases. It turns out that if all providers are assigned aliases, Terraform encounters difficulties. To resolve this error, it's essential to designate one provider without an alias.